# TypeORM throws QueryFailedError ER_TABLE_EXISTS_ERROR: Table 'courses' already exists in MySQL

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

When I set typeORM `synchronize:true` I get an
`[ExceptionHandler] ER_TABLE_EXISTS_ERROR: Table 'courses' already exists +3ms QueryFailedError: ER_TABLE_EXISTS_ERROR: Table 'courses' already exists` Error,
But when I make `synchronize:false` I dont get that error.
But I need to use `synchronize:true` in order to get the database changes.
Any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Well It's good for development but in production never do `synchronize: true`, you will regret it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to flush the table cache. For example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tablename` ;
FLUSH TABLES `tablename` ; /* or exclude `tablename` to flush all tables */
CREATE TABLE `tablename` ...
```

Also, you can try Dropping your database and then setting `synchronize: true` if you have that level of permission.

Comment: @TuharRoy  if I drop the table will I lose all my records of the database?

Comment: Even when I write a migration and make `synchronize: false` and `migration: true`  I get  that error, I tried flushing also

Comment: Yes, you will lose all your records. What i would suggest you to do is export your database and then try this.